# Как правильно: цвета ультрамарин или цвета ультрамарина?

Tags: склонение, падежи, окончания

Правильно

> глаза цвета ультрамарин

или

> глаза цвета ультрамарина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Был задан вопрос: как правильно?

Ответ может быть таким: (1) обе формы допустимы  (2) верна только одна форма, а другая является разговорной.  Соответственно, требуются пояснения по каждому ответу.

Мне представляется верным только один вариант: ***глаза цвета ультрамарин.***

УЛЬТРАМАРИН [нем. Ultramarin] I. -а; м. Яркая синяя краска. Сделать мазок ультрамарином. II. неизм.; в зн. прил. Ярко-синий. Цвета у.

Сравним две формы:

(1) ***Цвета ультрамарина.***  Здесь используется первое значение, где слово является **существительным** (краска). Мы получаем сочетание с падежным управлением: цвета (Р.п.) неба, цвета (Р.п.) ультрамарина, то есть цвета ярко-синей краски. **Но зачем использовать эту форму,** когда второе значение ориентировано именно  на тему обозначения цвета.

(2) ***Цвета ультрамарин***. В словаре дана пометка (**в знач. прил.**). А что это значит?  Существует особый класс **несклоняемых прилагательных**, куда входят и несколько слов со значением цвета.

https://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=9f1111cd-9a77-4878-9922-aa908d38b6ba

Разумеется, именно такой вариант желательно использовать в данном случае.

**Примечание.** В приведенной статье слова "ультрамарин" нет, так  как оно может быть как существительным, так и может употребляться в значении несклоняемого прилагательного.

Answer (score 6):

> *Глаза цвета ультрамарин*
>
> или
>
> *Глаза цвета ультрамарина?*

**В настоящее время используются оба варианта:**

*И добавьте к этому миндалевидные, слегка раскосые **глаза цвета ультрамарин** и ироничный взгляд* (Татьяна Соломатина. *Мало ли что говорят.* 2017).

*Её чёрные густые волосы, как у отца, и **глаза цвета ультрамарина**, как у матери, многим юношам в городе не давали спокойно спать по ночам* (Игорь Шиповских. *Ещё пять сказок о любви.* 2021).

Возможность несклонения слова *ультрамарин* при обозначении цвета («цвета ультрамарин») отмечена и некоторыми словарями. См. **БТС:**

> **УЛЬТРАМАРИН** [нем. Ultramarin] I. -а; ***м.*** Яркая синяя краска. *Сделать мазок ультрамарином*. **II. *неизм.; в зн. прил.*** Ярко-синий. *Цвета у.*
>
> [http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Ультрамарин&all=x](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A3%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD&all=x)

Comment: Спасибо, в БТС я заглянуть не догадался. Думаю, принят должен быть ваш ответ, а не мой.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "кармин" или "карминовый" не менее часто употребляется при указании на цвет чего-л., последний раз и недавно встречал его (много раз) в переведенных на русс-яз романах Герб. Уэлса.
Этому нужно создать правило(если его ранее небыло),  о том как писать окончание в случае какого-л. цвета ультраМодерн.Опять же, о "запатентовании" понятия  "синий" и изменении этого слова (чуть ли не во всех языках мира!) некой не безизвестной фирмой на другое.Представляете себе фразу "небеса цвета пепси".Еще лучше "Твои глаза пепси!". Какое сочетание рекламы и... чего?... филологии? А ведь ЕЙ ФОРДУ!, это многим нравиться... :) вероятно многие уж слыхали эту полуофициальную байку?